# InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError Google Maps API v3

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing in JavaScript/ASP.NET an app that uses Google Maps. I am getting the following alert dialog box:

> "This page was unable to display a Google Maps element. The provided
>   Google API key is invalid or this site is not authorized to use it.
>   Error Code: InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError"

This alert comes after I made the marker in the map from my localhost database. Before the map connect to the database, everything is working fine.

This is the javascript code :

```
private static string SetSourceScript()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        string markers = ProductAllLocationCatalog.GetAllLocation();

        sb.Append("<script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=MYKEY&sensor=false' runat='server'></script>");
        sb.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>                                                       ");
        sb.Append("   function initialize() {                                                            ");
        sb.Append("     var mapOptions = {                                                               ");
        sb.Append("        center : new google.maps.LatLng(-6.9027117, 107.6037877),                     ");
        sb.Append("        zoom : 9,                                                                     ");
        sb.Append("        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP                                      ");
        sb.Append("     };                                                                               ");
        sb.Append("     var myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);" + markers + "}");
        sb.Append("google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);                         ");
        sb.Append("</script>                                                                             ");
        //sb.Append("<script src='../js/MapScript.js' runat='server'></script>");

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static string GetSourceScript()
    {
        return SetSourceScript();
    }

<!--Code to call the map :-->
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; max-width: 950px; height:400px; text-align:center;"></div>
```

And this is how I get Latitude and Longitude from database :

```
public static string GetAllLocation()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
        StringBuilder sqlCmd = new StringBuilder();
        string markers = "";
        sqlCmd.Append("SELECT Lat, Lng, City FROM csr");

        SqlCommand cmd = GetCommand(conn, sqlCmd.ToString());

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            SqlDataReader reader = GetDataReader(cmd);
            int i = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                i++;
                markers +=
                    @"var marker" + i.ToString() + @" = new google.maps.Marker({" +
                        @"position : new google.maps.LatLng(" + reader["Lat"].ToString() + ", " + reader["Lng"].ToString() + ")," +
                        @"map : myMap, title:'" + reader["City"].ToString() + "'});" +
                    @"google.maps.event.addListener(marker" + i.ToString() + @",'click',function(marker" + i.ToString() + "," + i + ") {" +
                        @"return function() {" +
                            @"infowindow.setContent('" + reader["City"].ToString() + "');" +
                            @"infowindow.open(map, marker" + i.ToString() + ");" +
                        "}" +
                    @"})(marker" + i.ToString() + "," + i + "));";            
            }
            return markers;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Please help~~ Thank you!

By the way, I already set my api key, so it allow my IP Address and the references set to localhost/*

The marker from database is working fine. I could tell that because the map will dissapear after two seconds. So I already saw that the markers is there perfectly.

And, do I have to use Google Map for Work if I want the marker is from my database? Also how if I want this map can be accessed from many computers?

Comment: Are you using the correct API key? Did you go to the [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) and check your keys? Maybe generate a new key and try it?

Comment: Did you replace `MYKEY` with the correct key in your code here?  `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=MYKEY&sensor=false`

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yes, I already generate a new key and try it, but it doesn't change anything. And yes, I replace MYKEY with correct key from developer console

Comment: If you are developing on your local machine, I'd rather use no key (remove it from the API call). You don't **need** one. And no, you don't need Maps API for Work to display a marker from your database.